# Responsive nav with image, bottom border on hover that touches the nav bar

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The code I have here is functioning (on my screen),
however I was able to get it by using padding in px to display the bottom border for a so that it touches the navbar (appearing on the bottom of the navbar). My problem is, because this using px padding, on screen size changes it may not touch the navbar. Yes I am aware of media queries which I have to do anyway, but I am curious if my solution is the most efficient or if I am missing something. I worked on this for a few hours and I feel now is a good time to ask.

I used float/clearfix for the nav on preference, but I am fine to switch to inline-block if you guys think that is better.

To make sure you guys got what I want; here is an example screenshot of what I want my nav to have on hover.

[image]

here is my code snippet and this is a codepen with the example snippet http://codepen.io/willcodes/pen/gryvYN

Haven't asked a lot of questions so I hope this is enough information

```
<body>
    <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <!--      nav        -->
        <nav class="clearfix">
            <div class="logo clearfix"><img src="https://i.imgsafe.org/7531c53733.png" alt=""></div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blogs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="search"><a href="">SR</a></li>
                <li class="hamburger"><a href="">MN</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- landing stuff -->
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
        <p> Tagline oh yeah</p>
        <button class="btn">Features</button>
        <button class="btn">Get Started</button>
    </div>
    </header>


</body>
```

css:

```
.clearfix:after {visibility: hidden; display: block; font-size: 0; content: " "; clear: both; height: 0; }

* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
body,
html{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size:62.5%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}

header{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size:2.5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    background:black;
    background-size: cover;
    padding:1px;
    color: white;

}

p{
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-transform: none;
}

h1{
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:5%;
    padding: 1%;
    border:4px solid white;
    width:60%;
}

button{
    margin-bottom:2.5%;
    font-size:1.5rem;

}

.wrapper{
    width:70%;
    max-width:1480px;
    margin:1% auto;
    background: transparent;
}

/* nav */


nav{
    background: white;
    width:100%;

}

.logo{
    width:40%;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
  padding:10px;
}
.logo img{
    float:left;
    max-width:100%;
}

nav ul{
  margin:0;
  margin-top:2.5%;
    width:60%;
    float:left;
    font-size:1.2rem;
    text-align: right;
    padding:0;
}

nav ul li{
    margin-right:1.5%;
    float:left;
  list-style:none;
}

nav ul li a{
 text-decoration:none;
 color:black;
 display: block;
 padding:40px 0;
    border-bottom:5px solid transparent;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
  border-bottom:5px solid gray;
}
```

Comment: Are you certain you want a navigation bar to look that much like a banner ad?

Comment: hahahhaah, this is just an example, in my project it is not so black and white... although the designer will probably find that hilarious

Comment: :) Seriously took me a second to realize it was navigation in the CodePen, banner blindness and all that. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution works quite well. I tested it out on various resolutions and it worked fine. However, The problem lies in the fact that at a certain screen resolution, your navigation menu starts to break down into another line, disrupting the one line flow, and messing everything up. I personally found this occurs at 1053px and below, which is where you should declare a media query to either add some css to allow it to stay on one line for smaller devices.

Personally, I would suggest ensuring some way that the nav stays on one line until around 1024px, then anything below that just throw in a hamburger style nav button. Up to you though.

Comment: Yes thats the plan for media queries, I guess that settles that haha. I just thought there would be a better way instead of just guessing padding px

Comment: Well why don't you just put fixed px padding or margin or whatever you are using to create some spacing inside the navigation? That way you know exactly how many px you need. I like the idea of percentages too, but in regards to your specific scenario, I don't think they are absolutely necessary.